# what is meaning of using probs[range(6),y]

Tags: python, numpy

A python 2d numpy-array `probs` has the shape `(6,3)`, another 1d array `y` has a shape `(6,)`. what is the meaning of `probs[range(6),y]`?

For example:

```
import numpy as np

probs=np.array([[  1.,   2.,   3.],
                [  1.,   3.,   5.],
                [  1. ,  4.,   7.],
                [  1.,   5.,   9.],
                [  1.,   6.,  11.],
                [  1.,   7.,  13.]])

y= [0, 0, 1, 1, 2, 2]

probs[range(6),y]
```

Which rule is used here?

Comment: are you using numpy?

Comment: yes. I am using numpy. But, it appears numpy feature is not used in probs[range(6),y]

Comment: but `props` is a numpy array?

Comment: exp_scores = np.exp(scores)
probs = exp_scores / np.sum(exp_scores, axis=1, keepdims=True), it should be a np array.  "scores" is 6x3 array.

Comment: I've included a [mcve] in your question. If I changed anything that you didn't intended please [edit] it again. Please also have a look at the answer if it explains your question accuratly and if so please accept it and if not just put another comment here. :)

Answer (score 1):

The rule is simple it takes the first element of the `range(6)` as x coordinate and the first element of your `y` as y-coordinate for the first element. The second element of both indices is taken for the second element and so on.

That is also explained in the [`numpy indexing docs`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.indexing.html#advanced-indexing).

To explain it suppose you have a 3x3 array:

```
import numpy as np
array = np.arange(9).reshape(3,3)
array
```

```
array([[0, 1, 2],
       [3, 4, 5],
       [6, 7, 8]])
```

To get the `0,0` or the `1,2` element you can use integer indexing:

```
array[0,0]
# 0
array[1,2]
# 5
```

if you want both of them you can combine these two:

```
array[[0,1],[0,2]]
# array([0, 5])
```

So with `[range(6),y]` you are creating a new array with the elements:

```
# [0, 0], [1, 0], [2, 1], [3, 1], [4, 2], [5, 2]
```

because `range(6)` in this context is equivalent to `[0,1,2,3,4,5]`.

Comment: Thanks. array[[0,1],[0,2]] typo?  Should be array[[0,1],[1,2]]?

Comment: I tried print
  print array[[0,1],[1,2]] and get output [1 5], is it correct?

Comment: @Shun - Yes you are partially right. I wanted element `0,0` and `1,2` so the `array[[0,1],[0,2]]` was ok. I just messed but when copying the result. I've corrected it.

Comment: when I try to print array[[0,1],[0,2]], I got output [0 5], do I missed anything? Should I get 5 numbers?

Comment: @Shun - No the example in the answer is just about 2 elements. In your case you have two 6-element arrays so you get 6 elements in return.

Comment: Finally, I got it. Thank you so much.

Comment: @Shun No problem, when I started with numpy indexing that really confused me too :) Please don't forget to accept the answer.